# What is the time complexity of multiplication of 6 matrices of order n x n?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

A x B x C x D x E x F, where each matrix is a square matrix of order n x n ?

What is the time complexity of A x B x C X D x E X F ?

Comment: The time complexity of doing it once is still an area of research

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Time complexity of various matrix mult algorithms is documented quite well on line.

Answer (score 1):

The same as the complexity of multiplying two matrices of order n*n. That is, `O(n³)` if you use the naive algorithm. As long as the number of matrices is a constant, it does not affect the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: See [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm)